# Regex to get all data before second last special character

Tags: regex

I couldnt find any previously asked question similar to this. I need a regex to get all the data before second last special character.

For example:

```
suite 1, street 1, zip city, country
```

I need only `suite 1, street 1`.

I know how to get the data before just the last special character using `[^,]*$` but not the second last one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following regex and the first capturing group will have your desired substring:

```
(.*)(?:,[^,]*){2}$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/AWpsL3/1

Or if the tool you're using does support capturing groups, you can use the following regex with lookahead instead:

```
.*(?=(?:,[^,]*){2}$)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/AWpsL3/4

Comment: I've updated my answer with a solution that does not make use of a capturing group, in case the tool you are using does not support it. It would help if you told us which tool or programming language you're using regex with.

Answer (score 1):

you can use look ahead

```
.+(?=.*,.*,)
```

explanation

- `.+` matches everything until the position look head starts , if the look ahead does not fail
- Positive Look ahead `(?=.*,.*,)`
  asserts two commas exist at the end

[check demo](https://regex101.com/r/9JKhbd/2)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the implementation of regex, it may not support lookaround (which is what the above solution uses). A work around for this would be to perform a string split on your delimiter character (in this case, comma). Then perform a string join of the first two elements.

```
mystr = 'suite 1, street 1, zip city, country';
parts = mystr.split(',');
return parts[0]+','+parts[1];
```

Comment: Sorry, I need a single line regex, I cant use this code.

Answer (score 0):

Try `(([ \w]+,?){2})(?=,)` and dont use global flag (doesn't return after first match)

[regex](https://regex101.com/r/AWpsL3/5)

Comment: It matched all the data upto second comma not before second last comma.